# no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.enimbus.book.Post] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]

Tags: rest, android-studio, spring-boot

I am developing android app using restful service. I call get request from a url and it returns content type application/json;charset=UTF-8. I want to show return json data in my android view. to do that I use below code in android mainactivity

```
private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Post> {
    @Override
    protected Post doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            final String url = "http://192.168.0.100:8080/rposts/view/46";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Post post = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Post.class);
            return post;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Post post) {
        TextView PostIdText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_title);
        TextView PostContentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_body);
        PostIdText.setText(post.getTitle());
        PostContentText.setText(post.getBody());
    }

}
```

when I run my app it gives an error

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.enimbus.book.Post] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
                                                                              org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.enimbus.book.Post] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
   at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:79 undefined)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:484 undefined)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439 undefined)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237 undefined)
   at com.enimbus.book.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:123 undefined)
   at com.enimbus.book.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:116 undefined)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288 undefined)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237 undefined)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231 undefined)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112 undefined)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587 undefined)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841 undefined)
    11-02 14:34:39.194 27146-27146/com.enimbus.book D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    11-02 14:34:39.194 27146-27146/com.enimbus.book W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e90da0)
    11-02 14:34:39.204 27146-27146/com.enimbus.book E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.enimbus.book, PID: 27146
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.enimbus.book.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:137 undefined)
   at com.enimbus.book.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:116 undefined)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632 undefined)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177 undefined)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645 undefined)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102 undefined)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146 undefined)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653 undefined)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515 undefined)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291 undefined)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107 undefined)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using below dependencies in gradle app

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
```

}

returned json data when I test with postman

```
{
"id": 46,
"title": "hellov",
"slug": "tharu",
"postedOn": "08/12/2016 3:04:58 PM",
"keywords": [
    "i"
],
"tags": [
    "love"
],
"active": true,
"author": {
    "id": 20,
    "firstName": "Tharindu",
    "lastName": "Gihan",
    "email": "gihan@gmail.com"
},
"teaser": "<p>to</p>",
"body": "<p>you</p>"
```

}

Server side spring boot rest controller

```
package com.gihangreen.controller.rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.gihangreen.domain.Post;
import com.gihangreen.service.CommentService;
import com.gihangreen.service.PostService;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rposts")
public class PostRestController {

 private PostService postService;
 private CommentService commentService;

@Autowired
public PostRestController(PostService postService, CommentService    commentService) {
    super();
    this.postService = postService;
    this.commentService = commentService;
}

//get all posts
@RequestMapping( value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public Iterable<Post> list(){
    return postService.list();
}

//get post content by id
@RequestMapping(value="/view/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Post read(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id) {
    return postService.get(id);
}

//get post by author id
@RequestMapping(value="/byAuthor/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<Post> byAuthor(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id) {
    return postService.listByAuthor(id);
    
}

//search post by string
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<Post> search(@RequestParam("search") String search) {
    return postService.searching(search);
    
}


}
```

How I fixed this issue? help

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to first see what the data is being sent back?

```
 CURL http://192.168.0.100:8080/rposts/view/46 -v
```

Comment: I am a windows user how I execute above command. I used postman to view return data. At the bottom of this question, I added returned JSON

Comment: In PostMan, what is the Response "Content-Type" header? Is it "application/json"? or is it something else like "text/html"    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter supports JSON only, which could mean the server is returning incorrect content type.

Comment: Derric, inPostman Response "Content-type" header is "application/json" I added server side code. please look read method

Comment: Sorry hard to tell from looking at it. Can you copy paste the full HTTP Call? There are also tools like Fiddler and Moesif able to capture HTTP Calls easily for debugging. – Derric 2 days ago